# Why not the cron run?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to create a cron task in my debian system.

I do this

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add a line

```
10 17 * * * /home/userdir/cron/meiwei-slide-shoot.sh
```

And I do this at 17:00 and hope the script run at 17:10. But it doesnt work.

I have tried the script. It works well. But why not it run by cron?

Comment: Is the cron daemon started? Take a look at the cron logs to see if there was an error.

Comment: Is `meiwei-slide-shoot.sh` executable, and does it start with a shebang line specifying the shell to invoke?

Comment: why dont you test the script for every minute * * * * * /home/userdir/cron/meiwei-slide-shoot.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 If that works then change the timings and then test

Comment: Yeah, the script does work. I have tried and i `chmod` to make it executable.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I found some blogs on shell scripting and i know i shoud add `PATH` in the script. And then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the file is executable?

Have you added a line like:

```
touch /tmp/proof_that_i_am_running
```

to the top of the script to check whether it's starting, and just dropping out for some other reason, like an incomplete environment setup?

Have you received mail from `cron` containing the output/error?

Have you checked in the `cron` spool directory (such as `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`) to ensure the entry has been created?

There are a large number of things you could have missed, that's just the common ones, but a good start.

---

A good test is to add:

```
* * * * * date >>/tmp/crondates 2>&1
```

to your `crontab` and watch to see if that file appears.

Comment: I have tried this `* * * * * date >>/tmp/crondates 2>&1`. It works. But i still can not make my script executed.

Comment: @aisensiy: and putting the `touch` at the top of your script? What did that do?

Comment: I add this to my script `script.sh >/tmp/cron.log 2>&1` and it told me that the command can not be found. Maybe the root do not find dir /usr/local/bin?

Answer (score 1):

I would

1. check those file permissions to make sure the script can be executed by the cron user
2. log the stdout / stderr to a file to capture any errors e.g. `script.sh >/tmp/cron.log 2>&1`

`cron` processes run with a hugely cut-down environment and it's likely that you've either got execute permission issues or you're relying on an environment variable that isn't available. For what it's worth I always go through a couple of iterations each time I set up a `cron` job.

[This AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone) also contains some useful info.